# D3 map not rendered despite no errors on console

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'd like to print a D3.js map of provinces of Tuscany. I followed the instructions collected online for the below code (I use Flask to render it online):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js">    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div> 
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var width = 700,
  height = 300;

  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([0, 50])
  .scale(100)
  .rotate([0,0]);

  var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

  var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);

  var g = svg.append("g");

  d3.json("{{ url_for('static', filename='italy.json') }}",     function(error, topology) {
  console.log(topology);
  g.selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.ITA_adm2).features)
  .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
  console.log(g);
  });
    </script>
</html>
```

Looking at the JavaScript console it doesn't return any kind of error and when I used a `word.json` found online it worked. 
To produce my map I downloaded the Italy provinces GeoJSON (https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/blob/master/countries/italy/italy-provinces.json). I loaded it on the site mapshaper where I selected only elements with `NAME_1==Toscana`. Then I exported the result in topojson (for this reason you see `.ITA_adm2` in data because it is the valuename where geometries are stored).
The result doesn't give me any issue but it does show nothing either. I think the error could be related to the TopoJSON but It seem to be read well when I print out `console.log` values.

Comment: When using your code (and a local copy of the topojson you have linked to) I am unable to replicate your issue: http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/cadb3f0f3d617bbbff6b4ccaa5ce2126 . Can you share the topojson you have used, if that is the only thing different than you have shared, the problem is likely there.

Comment: bl.ocks.org/marco25d/02e8b8f525e0d67db919291b72cd4402 .Here it's render but still nothing in my code. There is surely a big problem in terms of scale but even make it bigger doesn't change nothing.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem in terms of scale, but also of centering. The features are there, but very small. Zooming in zooms to the center of the projection ([0,50]) - which is not where your features are - pushing the features beyond the svg. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588272/7106086 , it is the same issue: you need to zoom and scale. See this block with your data: http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/daa546359e5874216823e9ea1afc3bbc  In v4 you can use the fitExtent or fitSize method to automatically scale and translate your features, though there is a method for this in v3.